# ImportError: cannot import name 'faker' from partially initialized module 'faker' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, django

1. 1. from django.db import models

      ```
        # Create your models here.
      ```
   2. class Quiz(models.Model):

      ```
          quiz_title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
          num_questions = models.IntegerField(default=0)

          def __str__(self):
              return self.quiz_title


      class Question(models.Model):
          quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
          question_text = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
          question_num = models.IntegerField(default=0)
          answer = models.CharField(max_length=300)
          explanation = models.TextField(max_length=5000)

          def __str__(self):
              return str(self.question_num)





      class Choice(models.Model):
          question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
          choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
          correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)

          def __str__(self):
              return str(self.choice_text)
      ```

   from random import randint
   2. from faker import faker
   3. from quiz.models import Quiz, Question, Choice

   4. import random
   5. import django
   6. import os
   7. os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE',
      'schoolauthquiz.settings')
      django.setup()
   8. fakegen = faker()
   9. name = ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'MySQL','Python', 'jQuery',
      'Bootstrap4','Math']
   10. fake_num_questions = fakegen.randint(1, 10)
   11. def add_quiz():
   12. q = Quiz.objects.get_or_create(
   13. quiz_title=random.choice(name), num_questions=fake_num_questions)[0]
   14. q.save()
   15. return q
   16. 
   17. def populatequestion(N=10):
       for entry in range(N):
       quiz = add_quiz()

       ```
           fake_question_text = fakegen.question_text()
           # fake_question_num = fakegen.question_num()
           fake_answer = fakegen.answer()
           fake_explanation = fakegen.explanation()

           # fake_question = fakegen.question()
           fake_choice_text = fakegen.choice_text()
           fake_correct = fakegen.correct()

           Q = Question.objects.get_or_create(quiz=quiz, question_text=fake_question_text,
                                              question_num=fake_num_questions, answer=fake_answer,
       ```

       explanation=fake_explanation)[0]

       ```
           ch = Choice.objects.get_or_create(
               question=Q, correct=fake_correct, choice_text=fake_choice_text)[0]
       ```

       if **name** == '**main**':
       print("populating script!")
       populatequestion(10)
       print("populating populatequestion Complate!")

       `

Comment: Please review the code you have posted, it's probably that's incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

Check the naming of your files, i.e. if you named a file as `faker.py` that will cause circular import problem.

Answer (score 1):

I run in the same problem before. What you will need to do is add `blank=True` and ``` null=True``inside of each ``` ForeignKey()` methods.

For instance:

```
class Question(models.Model):

    """
    The Quiz models is defined as string.
    Since it is declared below this model.
    """
    quiz = models.ForeignKey('Quiz', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    ...


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  null=True, blank=True)
  ...
```

Bear in mind that the first post will have a null connection, but it can be updated after.

Comment: sir faker module using program is right or where is  worng  help me

Comment: Faker module use how? in model inheritance? i kown only single model how to write multiple model with inheritance that's why i am asking

Comment: How to populate this model using faker module or any other module any changes for model

Comment: abstract = True  ?